Can you integrate both sides of an equation with bounds with different differentials?
I'm wondering if generally $$f(x)dx=g(y)dy \implies \int^b_af(x)dx=\int^b_ag(y)dy$$
I know this question is like many others on this site but for some reason I get confused with bounds and need confirmation on this. Thanks!

In the first equation, what do the differentials there mean? What do they mean to you?

This looks like an exact ODE

I mean generally if dx and dy are different and so is f(x) and g(x). I might not be understanding you but I do want to.

You cannot do this. Take $x^2,dx=y,dy$ which is a separable ODE that is easy to solve. The integral transformation rule tells you how the bounds of the $dy$-integral are related to the bounds of the $dx$-integral.
